# Terminology for fake photograph

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I think there is a good chance that a new word or phrase has been coined to mean *fake photograph*.

Is there a single word to express it?

Comment: *Altered* is a good term that doesn't imply negative intent.

Comment: ***I*** think there's a good chance Thale already knew the verb *to photoshop*, and simply wondered if there was a corresponding derived single-word term for *a photoshopped image*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is *photoshop* relevant to *all* photo image manipulation? There *are* other digital applications capable of digital image manipulation *besides* photoshop. What about image manipulation on non digital imagery? Photoshop is an overused and often *incorrectly* used term.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: It's a new word, so I don't think you want to be *too* picky about exactly when it's being used "incorrectly". For example, it would definitely still be a photoshopped image if you'd happened to use something other than the eponymous Adobe product. I've no idea what you mean by *"image manipulation on non digital imagery"*, but I suppose as yet photoshopping doesn't include "staged" photographs. It might do one day soon, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well that's my point, according to OED, it would *not* be a photoshopped image if produced by another digital editing program: Photoshop, v. To edit, manipulate, or alter (a photographic image) digitally using *Photoshop* image-editing software. You probably think I'm being pedantic, but this site is *supposedly* about **correct** English word usage, so I'm being no more pedantic than anyone else here. Either a word is correctly used or it is **not**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Image manipulation on non digital imagery is exactly what it says it is - it's photographic retouching on a non digital image, in other words a conventional photograph. If you were referring to a photograph that was modified/retouched in the 1960's *before* Adobe Photoshop was invented, you would not claim it had been photoshopped would you?

Comment: @spiceyokooko: Like I said, it's a new word. There might have been a time in the past when some dictionary defined *to hoover* as *to clean a carpet using a vacuum cleaner made by Hoover*. I'm not saying you're being *pedantic* - I'm saying the new term doesn't yet have a precise meaning that you can say is the one and only "correct" one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OED seems to think so - it's defined it quite **clearly** or are you now saying OED is **wrong**? This is what I dislike about this stack, even when the dictionary says you are **WRONG** you still argue the toss about it!

Comment: I agree with FumbleFingers: _Photoshop_ in this context is being used as _genericized trademark_, much like _Band-Aid_ (for an adhesive bandage) or _Coke_ (for a carbonated cola drink).

Comment: "Deep fake" is a term I'm seeming more often. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PINeQV0LH6k

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can say that the photograph has been *doctored* if it was changed to deceive people.

Answer (score 45):

Normally if a photograph has been faked it is said to have been *Photoshopped*, or called a *Photoshop*, after the popular image editing software.

Sometimes this is shortened to *shopped* or *shop*, as in:

> That photo's a shop [or been shopped], I can see the pixels!!1

More general terms include *forgery*, *counterfeit* and of course *fake*.

[image: Man pointing at computer screen, saying "This looks shopped. I can tell from some of the pixels and from seeing quite a few shops in my time."]

Comment: I've heard people use the same phrase used for plastic surgery, i.e, 'It's had a little work done.'

Comment: The term "shop" has morphed even further into [**shoop**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shoop).

Comment: @MT_Head shoop de woop!

Comment: "shopped" is too casual a word. I would simply go with "illegitimate."

Comment: I think "photoshopped" and its derivatives are slang technical terms. I think they should be avoided unless its clear that the listener understands them.

Comment: And by the way Adobe forbids improper use of their product names, if that's of any interest. See http://www.adobe.com/misc/trade.html#section-4

Comment: Especially in regards to crudely done modifications I often seen photoChopped used sarcastically.

Comment: @s.m I was going to "google" another example and use a "sharpie" to write it on a "post-it" and "xerox" it for you, unfortunately I sneezed and had to find a "kleenex" but all the medicine cabnet had where "Q-tips" and by the time I got back I forgot... [thank you wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks#List_of_protected_trademarks_frequently_used_as_generic_terms)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that's a good one! I didn't say I agree with that, though. Quite the opposite, actually: I think that Adobe (as a company, not talking about individuals here) often acts as if they were a bunch of morons. You have a product that's become so wildly successful that it has become a new word in one language (or possibly more)? I would be happy about that. But this is OT, I'm afraid.

Comment: Which part of that image looks "shopped" to you? The reason I ask, this photo doesn't look edited and the "shopped" and "photoshopped" terms are grossly overused as by people with little knowledge about image editing that want to sound smart. Not that I'm trying to belittle you, just drawing attention to that overuse. This term is in similar vain to people saying powerpoint when they mean presentation. As if using powerpoint to make bad presentations is something to be proud of.

Comment: @Chris: I didn't add the image, but it's a joke and the caption is referring to what the men can see in their computer screen, which we can't see and don't need to for the joke to work.

Comment: @Hugo: Sorry, duh moment. I thought the text was added by poster, instead it's part of the illustration. I blame this crap monitor at work.

Answer (score 10):

It would be perfectly legitimate to say such a photo was a forgery.

Comment: Forgery requires intent to deceive

Answer (score 5):

*CG* is a term that could be used for a created (or faked) photo. It is short for a computer-generated image. "CG" is not exactly equivalent to "fake," but CGs are often contrasted with "real photos."

This is an interesting site that lets you guess if a series of photos are real or CG: http://area.autodesk.com/fakeorfoto/challenge  (I was so-so at the challenge.)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the question asked, and may therefore be better as a comment.

Comment: @Christi, CG is a term for a created (or fake) photo. I will edit my answer to say that, I guess.

Comment: The link to the site is down. Could you provide a new one?

Comment: @Epitorial, I have done so.

Comment: I've heard of the characters that were CGI for computer generated imagery/computer generated images.

Answer (score 4):

It can be a

1. Staged photograph (To imply the things going on in the photographs have been planned)
2. Manipulated Image
3. Digital Manipulation
4. Edited in Post
5. Photoshoped

Comment: I've personally never came across a fake photograph, unless somebody was a really excellent painter, drawer, etc...

Answer (score 4):

A snarky coined term that I have seen is "**fauxtograph**" (pronounced the same way as "photograph"). Similar terms are "**fauxtography**" and "**fauxtoshopped**". This is a jeu de mot with the French word "faux", meaning "false".

Comment: These are nice terms, but unfortunately I would think they only work when written; when spoken they would sound too similar to the originals.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange, that no one has mentioned *[hoax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoax)* yet. It's a bit broader term, because it is not used to describe photographs only.

Answer (score 1):

Instagram/Instagramming is another - "aura" enhancing - form of photo manipulation.

In old days, it was airbrushing. "Just airbrush the b------ out" a famous movie actress once told a fashion photographer who didn't know what to do with a photo that included her and her husband (a Pepsi executive) who had recently died. But even in the 19c clouds were "burned into" otherwise eggshell white skies. Red, blue or green filters were used to soften or roughen the appearance of skin.

"Digitally manipulated" as above, "post-processed" or "photomontaged".

Answer (score 0):

The technical term is *retouched*.

From Oxford English Dictionary:

> retouch, v
>
> To improve or repair the appearance of (a painting, composition, photographic negative or print, etc.) by small alterations or fresh touches; to touch up.

In use:

> 1979   N. Farah Sweet Sour Milk v. 78   There was the photograph of the All-Powerful retouched to make him look much younger and handsomer.

In general usage (particularly within the print industry) the original meaning has been expanded to include photographic prints or negatives that have been significantly altered or changed from the original to constitute a *fake* photograph. A fake is clearly defined as having been manipulated to represent something that is not real.

Answer (score 0):

**Pseudo-photograph**

This term is used in the UK Protection of Children Act 1978, as amended in 1994, and defined as "*an image, whether made by computer-graphics or otherwise howsoever, which appears to be a photograph*"