# What's the word for the activity of distorting video/voice records to trick people?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the activity of distorting video clips or voice records in an editing program so as to trick people? (For instance, adding a sound into a voice record which was not there in the original.) What I'm looking for might be the equivalent of "photoshopping" in video or voice editing.

P.S.: Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ suggested that it is "deepfake" and that seems to be the only possible option for the moment.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Does "Deep Fake" work? This is a recent phenomenon so accepted language may be only jargon.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot. And there is no other such word other than "deepfake", I guess?

Comment: The word you are looking for is: doctered, to docter a text, by extension, a video. Deepfake is completely different. It means creating a new thing that is fake out of a not fake original thing.

Comment: Hi @Lambie We are trying to clarify and  develop the Q...plz cooperate. "Doctored" can include most any forgery...this is specific to audio/visual

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ I dunno, can these types of questions be helped?

Comment: @Lambie It has the potential of being interesting...we need to encourage original ideas

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ Deepfaking is a *particular method* of digital forgery that uses neural networks to alter media. There are certainly many other ways to alter audio/video, deepfaking is just one method to accomplish that goal quickly, cheaply, and believably. The film Forrest Gump, for example, inserted the titular character into historical footage, which fits the OP's usage to a tee, but this was certainly not accomplished by deepfaking. I don't think deepfake has yet come to encompass any video edit, like Photoshop has come to encompass any photo edit, whether done with PS or not.

Comment: Hello @NuclearHoagie I am not answering, merely suggesting. I think this is an interesting question that needs development. Once we have clarification...How about a formal answer?

Comment: It might help to give some specific examples. There's a lot of difference between putting echo on a recording to make it sound like it's in a church (that would be a simple example of distorting a recording), and inserting a new figure into a video (called [compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing)). Is it being done for malicious or criminal reasons, or to create something artistic like a horror movie or a joke? There are terms for some aspects of this, but maybe nothing general for everything you want.

Comment: Check out the answers to the question about [a word for fake photographs](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/72658/191178) — there's substantial overlap.